# Question about In-States in S.Weinberg Lectures On Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, scattering, quantum-states, s-matrix-theory

At the beginning of chapter 7 *Potential Scattering* of [*Lectures on Quantum Mechanics by S. Weinberg*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/lectures-on-quantum-mechanics/F739B9577D2473995024FA5E9ABA9B6C), he has introduced the in states (in Heisenberg picture) $\Psi^{\text{in}}_{\pmb{k}}$, which indicates the state consists of a particle with momentum $\hbar \pmb{k}$ far from scattering center.

Going deeper into the meaning of in-states, he said to consider the *superposition* of states with a spread of energies with time dependence, that is,
$$\Psi_{g}(t) = \int{d^3k\,g(\pmb{k})\exp\left(\frac{-i\hbar t\pmb{k}^2}{2\mu}\right)\Psi^{\text{in}}_{\pmb{k}}}\tag{7.1.3}$$
where $\mu$ would be the particle's mass.

My question, why we would have to consider the superposition here?

My brief thought is that the *same particle* with possible momentum should all be taken into account, but I'm not sure this is correct.

Comment: I don't have that book, but it's probably because the states of definite momentum are not normalizable.